# Can I install XP SP3 over an XP SP2 with NOD32 installed?

Tags: windows-xp, upgrade, nod32

I have installed ESET NOD32 v4.0 on a Windows XP SP2 and I would like to install SP3. Do I *have* to uninstall NOD32 before I upgrade to SP3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it would be a good idea to disable the real-time scanning before running the upgrade.  You don't want the virus scanner interfering with the installation and causing problems with the upgrade.

While it *shouldn't* cause a problem, you'll be in a bad way *if* it does.

Comment: Both ESET NOD32 v4.0 and VMware Workstation 7.0 work fine, they seem unaffected by the upgrade. Great job, guys, your apps are rock solid :)